# Is it possible to integrate AppFabric into an SSRS implementation?

Tags: caching, ssrs-2008, appfabric

That's the question, I guess. We have some fairly complex queries (in sprocs) driving our SSRS implementation. The data is only refreshed on a daily basis so instead of fetching this data each time, I'd like to see about caching it in AppFabric (or Redis or something, just assumed that MS would probably allow for greater integration with their own) for better response time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

entirely possible with a service data source. Your service would be able to connect to your appfabric/redis instance.